# Is there Amazon firewall\port sniffer metrics on Amazon CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there Amazon firewall\port sniffer metrics on Amazon CloudWatch? The task is: track traffic on Amazon EC2 machine on specific port. Is this possible via Amazon CloudWatch API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of such metrics being publicly available.  However, given the task:

> track traffic on Amazon EC2 machine on specific port

you can certainly monitor the traffic on a given EC2 instance using a tool like:

- iptraf
- tcpdump

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html #13 and #14 for details.